# Locale-sensitive string sort in Dart

Tags: sorting, dart, locale

I need to sort a `List<String>`. Its elements might contain non-ASCII characters (think é, ž, Æ, ...). Is there a way to do this in Dart while being locale-aware?

Something like [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) in Javascript.

Some examples:

Czech (cs_CZ)

```dart
List<String> czechWords = ['čeština', 'cvrček', 'chleba',];

// expected after calling a localizedSort() or similar method

List<String> czechWordsSorted = ['cvrček', 'čeština', 'chleba',];
```

Comment: Can you give a list of words and then show the expected sorting order? It makes it easier to try different solutions before posting an answer.

Comment: @julemand101 added a couple of examples

Comment: As a Dane I am confused with your last example since `Æ` does not come before `A`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danish_and_Norwegian_alphabet

Comment: @julemand101 I must've mixed that up, sorry. Removed the misleading example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dart platform libraries do not currently have any locale-specific string sorting or comparison functionality.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone still has the same problem, here is how I solved this (for Czech in the example).

### Rationale

This works by substituting the diacritics chars away & then comparing on normal strings. The trick is to expand both the normalized & unnormalized strings, but so that the order is as You want it.

For example, I want to have `u` before `ú` which is before `ů`, so I can ensure this if I substitute all `u` for `ua`, `ú` for `ub`, and `ů` for `uc`.

Another thing is solving `ch`; this is done by substituting `h` for `ha` and `ch` for `hb` (so that each `ch` char is just after `h`).

Both cases need to be done in one pass, as they interact.

### Solution

```dart
const Map<String, String> collTable = {
  "a": "aa", "á": "ab", "A": "Aa", "Á": "Ab", "c": "ca", "č": "cb", "C": "Ca",
  "Č": "Cb", "d": "da", "ď": "db", "D": "Da", "Ď": "Db", "e": "ea", "é": "eb",
  "ě": "ec", "E": "Ea", "É": "Eb", "Ě": "Ec", "i": "ia", "í": "ib", "I": "Ia",
  "Í": "Ib", "n": "na", "ň": "nb", "N": "Na", "Ň": "Nb", "o": "oa", "ó": "ob",
  "O": "Oa", "Ó": "Ob", "r": "ra", "ř": "rb", "R": "Ra", "Ř": "Rb", "s": "sa",
  "š": "sb", "S": "Sa", "Š": "Sb", "t": "ta", "ť": "tb", "T": "Ta", "Ť": "Tb",
  "u": "ua", "ú": "ub", "ů": "uc", "U": "Ua", "Ú": "Ub", "Ů": "Uc", "y": "ya",
  "ý": "yb", "Y": "Ya", "Ý": "Yb", "z": "za", "ž": "zb", "Z": "Za", "Ž": "Zb",
};
String collKeys = collTable.keys.join("");
final RegExp keysPat = RegExp(r"(cH|ch|CH|Ch|h|H)|([" + collKeys + r"])");

bool isUpperCase(String str){
  return str.toUpperCase() == str;
}

String collStr(String str){
  return str.replaceAllMapped(keysPat, (match){
    assert((match[1] == null) != (match[2] == null));
    if(match[1] != null) {
      // ch group = either h or ch
      String g = match[1]!;
      if (g.length == 1) {
        // h => ha, H => Ha
        return "${g}a";
      } else {
        assert(g.length == 2);
        // need to keep the case of the letters
        String subc = isUpperCase(g[0]) ? 'H' : 'h';
        // ch => hb, Ch => Hb, CH => Hb, cH => hb
        return "${subc}b";
      }
    }
    // diacritics
    return collTable[match[2]]!;
  });
}

int cmpColl(String a, String b){
  return collStr(a).compareTo(collStr(b));
}
```

### Usage

You can then use it like this:

```dart
 List<String> czechWords = ['čeština', 'cvrček', 'děda', 'chleba', 'czechia', 'houska', 'imbecilní'];
  for(var w in czechWords){
    debugPrint("$w -> ${collStr(w)}");
  }
  czechWords.sort(cmpColl);
  debugPrint(czechWords.toString());
```

Which prints:

```
čeština -> cbeasbtaianaaa
cvrček -> cavracbeak
děda -> daecdaaa
chleba -> hbleabaa
czechia -> cazaeahbiaaa
houska -> haoauasakaa
imbecilní -> iambeacaialnaib
[cvrček, czechia, čeština, děda, houska, chleba, imbecilní]
```

### Disclaimer

This definitely needs more testing :-)

## Edit:

The code for comparing `ch` is still not perfect. It is not clear, how the order should really be with capitalization, e.g. `Ch` vs. `CH`, `cH` vs `ch`, etc. Some of these might not be a valid czech letter... Right now, the `Ch` and `CH` are both treated as capital `ch`, so order is the same (== resulting order depends on whether dart `sort` is stable).